# 'float' object has no attribute 'rolling' when using lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

So I'm trying to calculate the z score using the lambda function.

Here's the code,

```
zscore_fun_improved = lambda x: ((x - x.rolling(window=200, min_periods=20).mean()) / x.rolling(window=200, min_periods=20).std())
df.Close.apply(zscore_fun_improved)
```

But it gives me the following error,

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'rolling'
```

What am I doing wrrong?

Comment: Please post your dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a `Series` to `apply`, the (lambda) function receive a scalar (a float here). If you pass a `DataFrame` to `apply`, the (lambda) function receive a `Series`.

So you don't need `apply` here:

```
zscore_fun_improved(df.Close)
```

Demo:

```
# DataFrame -> apply get Series
>>> df.apply(type)
open     <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
close    <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
dtype: object

# Series -> apply get scalar values
>>> df['close'].apply(type)
0    <class 'float'>
1    <class 'float'>
2    <class 'float'>
3    <class 'float'>
4    <class 'float'>
Name: close, dtype: object
```